# AJAX data, understanding as to what this actually does

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I found some old code which I am trying to understand and unfortunately I did not leave comments which leads to my difficulties. Even with the jQuery documentation, I can't wrap my head around it; I really have looked, but I still don't understand. This program is basically a chat where you type your name and your message and click submit. Then it displays your message in a chat box similar to Facebook. Here is the working code:

My JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var shout = $('#shout').val();
        var outText = 'name=' + name + '&shout=' + shout;

        if (name == '' || shout == '') {
            alert("Please fill in your name and shout");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "database.php",
                data: outText,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#shouts ul').prepend(html);
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

and my PHP

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','muntasirshoutbox');

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['shout']))
{

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['name']);
    $shout = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['shout']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO shouts(name,shout) ";
    $query.= "VALUES ('$name','$shout')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    if(!$result)
    {
        echo "doesent work".mysqli_error($connection);
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<li>'.$name.': '.$shout.'</li>';
    } 


}
?>
```

So I am confused as to what outText is actuallly **doing**, the reason I am confused is because, I was under the impression that my PHP was printing the text inside the chat box when I do this `echo '<li>'.$name.': '.$shout.'</li>';`, but after experimenting with `outText`, I noticed that if I change some stuff with `outText` the message I type in wont appear at all in the chat box, or it will appear with whatever string I added to it. What exactly is this doing?!

Comment: `outText` is the request object which is passed to the `php` which inturn will be inserted into the database. It holds `name` and `shout (message)`. If you change `outText` then make sure it is in the valid format i.e it should have 2 properties as those are being validated in the php while inserting into the database.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what outText needs to be set too, why does it need two properties? For example why cant outText = "hello"?, sorry I still dont really understand..

Comment: Because its like its forming this url `database.php?name=Joe&shout=waz+up` ... only not really, because its POST rather than GET. But if it was GET it would literally be making that URL.  Why is there two parameters? Because you have two parameters.

Comment: `outText` is nothing but a `property`. You need to fill it with whatever data you need to save in the database. In the above you are trying to save `name` and `message` hence you combined both of them into one property called `outText` and passing to the service.  It's basically a good practice.

Comment: In other words (continuing my train of thought above), you need to go through a basic tutorial on "HTML forms". You can't skip the basics.

Comment: I see, I think I get it guys, however what exactly is the neccesity of the & before shout?

Comment: in urls you need a reserve character to determine what breaks the parameter list up. `database.php?name=Joe&shout=waz+up` is clear you have two parameters. `database.php?name=Joeshout=waz+up` Now its only one, and its messed up.

Comment: Great, I will look up some info on GET and POST to further my knowledge, much appreciated :)

Comment: By the way, does outText have two parameters because of the two variiables shout and name before it? Or is it because in the PHP file we said $name = my_escape_real_string  etc etc. Where is it getting the knowledge of two parameters?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to ask the other part of my question, also why do we need to return false? Why don't we want the farm to actually submit? @developerwjk

Comment: if you dont use `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` the page will refresh which is not the essence of ajax

Comment: i.e, any ajax request requires us to return false? @KimOliveros

Comment: it actually varies I think you use it when dealing with forms only. at the very least that's how I do it. but for `onLoad` data I believe its not necessary unless there are other things that will happen when that certain data is fetched from your backend